# Flutter get VideoPlayerController url from api

Tags: flutter, video-player

flutter vidoe controller at initState api has not request yet..

```
 void initState() {
        super.initState();
        **initializePlayer(url);**
      }
```

How should initialize video controller in init state with.. URL is get form future from snapshop..

```
Future<void> initializePlayer({String url}) async {
    _vidController = VideoPlayerController.network(url);
    await _vidController.initialize();

    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _vidController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
    setState(() {});
  }

body: FutureBuilder(
          future: Provider.of<ApiService>(context, listen: false)
              .getLessonDetail(
                  courseId: widget.courseId, lessonId: widget.lessonId),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Lesson> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final lesson = snapshot.data;


                String videoUrl =
                    "${AppURL.assetFromJr}video/course_${lesson.courseId}/chapter_${lesson.chapterId}/${lesson.lessonMobileVideo}?token=$videoNetworkToken}";
                **initializePlayer(url: videoUrl);**
```

How to play video without calling in initState or Playing video link from snapshot data url..

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should move your future into initState:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
Future future;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // NOTE this! we put future here instead of in the build!
   future = Provider.of<ApiService>(context, listen: false)
        .getLessonDetail(courseId: widget.courseId, lessonId: widget.lessonId);
    future.then(() async {
      _vidController = VideoPlayerController.network(url);
      await _vidController.initialize();

      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _vidController,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: true,
      );
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_vidController == null)
      return Text('loading...');
    else
      return YourVideoWidgetUsingTheControllers(use_your_future: future);
  }
}
```

Comment: await _vidController.initialize(); can't use this line..

Comment: @YeHtunZ hi, did you solve it? If so, you can mark this answer as accepted and give a vote up :)

Comment: how can i use "final future" in widget build..  do this ok but i have to use api call again in widget build ..same api call twice..